# Dereferencing a temporary pointer to initialize a reference member variable

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, c++17, lifetime

I am working with an external library which can hold large data structures. Calls to it return pointers to objects which it manages:

```cpp
class ExternalLib {
public:
  int* GetLargeObject() { return &large_object; };

private:
  int large_object = 1;
};
```

I am trying to write a wrapper for this external library which can hold a const reference to the large data structure I am interested in:

```cpp
class ExternalLibraryWrapper {
public:
  ExternalLibraryWrapper() : large_object_ref(*ext.GetLargeObject()){};

private:
  ExternalLib ext;
  const uint &large_object_ref;
};
```

However, I get the compiler warning:

> Reference member 'large_object_ref' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object [clang: dangling_member]

From my understanding, `ext.GetLargeObject()` returns a temporary pointer to the address of `(*this).ext.large_object`. Shouldn't the compiler know that the constructed object `&large_object_ref` isn't actually binding to a temporary object?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are trying to store a `const` reference to something that is not a `const` to begin with, so the compile creates a temporary to satisfy the binding. That would account for the warning. Why do you need to store a reference at all?  What is wrong with simply storing the original pointer and using it as-is? `class ExternalLibraryWrapper { public: ExternalLibraryWrapper() : large_object_ptr(ext.GetLargeObject()){}; private: ExternalLib ext; int *large_object_ptr; };`

Comment: This looks fundamentally sketchy to me.  You are using another member in an initializer list, assuming that object is already constructed.  This might not be the case, and is probably the reason this warning is being emitted by the compiler, in a roundabout way.

Comment: Why not wrap it with a shared pointer?

Comment: Shared pointers should only be used when the ownership of an object is shared. That's not the case here. The ownership of `large_object` is well defined. Whether it should be defined they way it is is another matter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That did the trick. I removed the `const` from the reference and it worked. I could use a  raw pointer but I tend to avoid them unless necessary.

Comment: @paddy I deliberately ordered the member variables so that `ext` is constructed before `large_object_ref` is assigned.

Comment: As a followup question, suppose `large_object` had methods which returned pointers to its own members like `large_object.also_large`. Is there an idiom for wrapping such objects in a way that would guard against invalidating wrappers which contained this pointer? I cannot change the library to use shared pointers so I think I would just have to warn against this possibility in documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Adding `const` should not cause a temporary to be materialized!  We accept arguments by const-reference all the time without expecting copies.  My crystal ball says that there’s a type mismatch in the real code that allows an implicit conversion—that or a compiler bug.

Comment: @DavisHerring Upon looking at the actual code, I think you are right. The type of the const reference was slightly different from the member initializer argument in the real code: `const implicitly_convertible_from_int &large_object_ref`

Comment: @segfault; Then you need to edit your question to do that, so we can answer it with “the implicit conversion is biting you”, or we need to close it as not reproducible (since the code as given works).

Comment: I will change the const reference parameter to `uint` so the same type of problem arises in the simplified case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A temporary is materialized when binding a reference when the initializer is a **prvalue** or when type of the initializer **differs** from the type of the reference by **more** than *cv*-qualifiers but can be converted to it (unless of course that conversion is user-defined and yields a reference).  (This case is rejected in the case of an lvalue reference to non-const; the `const U&` case is accepted for historical reasons.  It would have been nicer to have `const T&&` from the beginning and have *it* mean “you may pass temporaries, and I won’t modify whatever you pass”, but that’s not where we are.)

Obviously dereferencing a **pointer** produces an lvalue, so this warning (very useful since it’s impossible to use the reference so initialized!) indicates that the type mismatch pertains in your case.